# Symfony 4 front controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-flex, symfony4, symfony-recipe

Symfony 4 resigns on **app.php** and **app_dev.php** front controllers. Now it will be only one **index.php**. We can manipulate dev and prod environment in **.env** file. Please tell me is it only one way to change environment? I can't do that from the browser (as it was previous app and app_dev files)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You control what is in the index.php file, so you can arrange to include a different `env` file according to the rules that you decide.

For example, you can set a variable in the Apache vhost or Nginx FastCgi configuration, based on the URL you are visiting from - such as `APP_ENV=/home/myname/app-name/dev.env` or on a live server: `APP_ENV=/etc/app-name.prod.env` set as you like, or you could list both of them in the index.php and choose which one from there - although taking the option out of the code and setting it in a server configuration would probably be safer in the long term.